# Lazy loading/dynamic binding vs Safety

Tags: c++, design-patterns, software-design, dynamically-generated

First off, I think the term I want is neither "lazy loading" nor "dynamic binding". I don't know the correct term, but I'll edit this question when I do.

I'm connecting processing objects to create a data flow A->B:

**Method 1: Connect during Instantiation**
Code: https://ideone.com/Rsqabi

```
class Consumer {
public:
    virtual void consume(int data) = 0;
};

class A {
public:
    A(Consumer& consumer) : consumer_(consumer) {}
    void process(int data) { consumer_.consume(data); }
private:
    Consumer& consumer_;
};

class B : public Consumer {
public:
    B() {}
    void consume(int data) { /* consume data */ }
};
```

I have to have a Consumer instance handy to instantiate A:

```
int main() {
    B* b_ = new B();
    A a_ = A(*b_);
    a_.process(5);
    return 0;
}
```

**Method 2: Connect after Instantiation**
Code: https://ideone.com/5ij0yZ

What I really want is to choose my Consumer after instantiating A:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    void attachConsumer(Consumer* consumer) { consumer_ = consumer; }
    void process(int data) {
        // must always check consumer_ here!
        consumer_->consume(data);
    }
private:
    Consumer* consumer_;
};
```

and then:

```
int main() {
    A a_ = A();
    // ... for reasons I won't tell you, B must be created later than A ...
    B* b_ = new B();
    a_.attachConsumer(b_);
    a_.process(5);
    return 0;
}
```

**A better model?**

Method 1 is great because I always know the reference is valid. It's bad that it's inflexible.

Method 2 is great because I can choose down the road which Consumer to attach (or re-attach,  if state is safely considered). It's bad because pointers are dangerous.

Is there a Method 3 that satisfies the plus's of both models? Where I don't always need to check if my consumer is valid and attached, but that also allows dynamic connectivity?

What is the correct term for the difference in the models? I don't think it's lazy loading nor dynamic binding. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 leads to memory leak, because have to release Consumer, after A will be deleted. Reference will be valid, but it will not destroy object when will be destroyed, so you still need to "remember" about releasing B, that removes advantage of 1st method.

Use std::shared_ptr to hold B, if you afraid to forget to release B, and want to be sure you hold it.

And don't forget to add "explicit" to constructor with one parameter.